# How can I show html on WordPress content?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-type

I have a custom WordPress theme where user can post. I use the WP Editor (only text mode) to write the content, and then on the post page i Show the content calling  **the_content();** function. But then when I'm going to see the post it shows the html code.. Look: (the content is the text inside the blue div)

[image]

How can I show the text in bold for example? :S I tried also to put  but the result is the same..
Mi code where i call the content is this:

```
<div class="content_"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
```

I don't know why it is showing the html code..

Comment: Have you ever heard of XSS?  You are asking for it.

Comment: No.. I don't know what is it.. is this? https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you are printing to the page exactly the user's input, what will prevent them from putting malicious javascript into the input field?  It will then be executed every time you'll try to print the content of their input.

Comment: But I use the WP Editor to write the content and I think it only allows to put html.. I only want to allow users to put text in bold, underline, etc..

Comment: Maybe `the_content()` override along the way. Switch theme and see it works? If not disable plugins and see. I don't see any error in the code.  And also go to html mode in the editor and check the code make sure it's not sanitize